# Почему во фраме грузится исходник php скрипта вместо ответа?

Tags: php, html

При клике по ссылке грузится исходник php вместо ответа, как правильно получить ответ скрипта в html?

index.htm:

```
<frameset cols = 250px,*>
  <frame src = "menu.htm" />
  <frame src = "main.htm" name="main"/>
</frameset>
```

menu.htm:

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="./folder/mega.php" target="main">Mega</a>
</body>
</html>
```

main.htm:

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

mega.php:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<HTML>
<BODY>
<?php
  echo '  Hello world!</ br>';
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Начать стоит с логичного вопроса — а почему вы решили, что php-скрипт вообще должен был выполниться? Что вы предприняли для того, чтобы его кто-нибудь выполнял?

Comment: @andreymal логичный вопрос, согласен. Я как раз в поисках ответа, как это осуществляется правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В запускаемой среде (на сервере или локальном ПК) нет PHP.

Comment: установлен xammp, если запускаю напрямую mega.php всё прекрасно отрабатывает

Comment: @Isaev в чём отличие между «при клике по ссылке» и «запускаю напрямую»?

Comment: @andreymal, понял, я балбес, спасибо) работает